# How to install RODBC driver for SQL Server 2016 R Services

Tags: sql-server-2016, r-services

I'm trying to get started with R services on SQL Server 2016. I was following [this example from MS on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4AYr0QIwdQ).

2 min 22sec into the vid John shows a reference to library(RODBC)... which I don't have. So I have downloaded the [RODBC driver from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html)

According to the documentation:

> RODBC is simple to install, and binary distributions are available for
>   Windows from CRAN

But it provides no further details about how to install it. It mentions an *ODBC Driver Manager* but not much more than that.

So.. How do I install RODBC?

Do I unzip it to a specific path? 
Is there a utility or tool required to install it?
Do I run a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install R packages in SQLServer 2016, you first have to launch **R GUI** (somewhere like *D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\bin\x64\Rgui.exe*).

If your server is connected to the web, you can launch a :

```
install.packages("RODBC")
```

Otherwise, download the package (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html), put it your server, for instance in a folder D:\R_Packages, and launch the R command :

```
setwd("D:/R_Packages")
install.packages("RODBC_1.3-14.zip", repos=NULL)
```

This second method is not very convenient in case of package dependencies : you'll have to download / install manually all the packages needed....

Anyway, in you want RODBC to access SQLServer databases, maybe you don't need it.
Have a look at [sp_execute_external_script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604368.aspx) procedure which help you to connect directly R and SQLServer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestions but am now getting errors about paths. My default directory is mapped to a network drive. Once I figure that out I'll come back to this. Cheers.

Comment: @Peter : what kind of error do you have ?